# Extract `Moped::BSON::Document` attributes in Ruby hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

In Mongoid 3.0.21, how to get all model's attributes as a plain Ruby `Hash`?

Calling either `#attributes` or `#raw_attributes` returns `Moped::BSON::Document`.  While it actually extends `Hash`, <del>several hash method does not work as expected.  Particularly `#except` returns unmodified `self`, not hash with given keys stripped off</del>.

**Update**: `Moped::BSON::Document` properly inherits behavior of `Hash`.  I was trying to name attributes with symbols, not strings, that's why `#except` didn't work.  Shortly: do `except('pictures')`, not `except(:pictures)`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Hash[e.attributes]
```

where e is your model instance

Comment: Thanks! I knew there must be some elegant solution like this!

Comment: You may want to use ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess instead of plain Hash to be able to access values using both Strings and Symbols

Comment: I surely can, thanks.  But the main issue was I couldn't access attribute names at all because they are indexed with strings, not symbols.  This is different from I am used to (ActiveRecord).

Answer (score 4):

I apologize for bumping something so old, but I wanted to leave this here for myself and all the future people who run into this same issue. I am using the Mongoid ORM for Rails, which uses Moped internally for its interaction with MongoDB.

This gem has now saved me hours and hours of manually converting things to `Hash` or `HashWithIndifferentAccess`: https://github.com/mindscratch/mongoid-indifferent-access.

Essentially it seems to have some sort of pre-return hook that automatically converts all documents coming from MongoDB to type `HashWithIndifferentAccess`.

Not looking for points on this. Just wanted to leave this here because it is the top Google result for this issue and it saved me from going insane.